# Woocommerce - Alternative h1 title of My Account page for not logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account

I have set up our bakeries web store in a way that any woo commerce page is only accessible for logged in users. Now I am looking for a way to change the title of h1 on the My Account page in order to display something different for not logged in users. Has anyone an idea how to achieve that? Thanks for your input! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a built in function to check if a user is logged in.

```
<?php
    //Built in Wordpress function that checks if the user is signed in
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //If the user is logged in
        echo '<h1>Logged in title</h1>';
    } else {
       //If user is not logged in
       echo '<h1>Not logged in title</h1>';
    }
?>
```

You will need to modify the Woocommerce template by overriding it.

```
Example: To override the admin order notification, copy: woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
```

Comment: Thx a lot, that will be a guidance! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

----(Update)----

I was wrong… Woocommerce My account **is a page**. The `<h1>page title</h1>` is the title of your page, so you will need to change it, in the **wordpress** template for **pages** in your theme (Each theme is different) and *not in woocommerce templates*.

Once you have found this template in your theme folder, you will use a conditional in an if statement around the `<h1>page title</h1>`:

```
// When user is on my account page and not logged in
if (is_account_page() && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'.__("My custom title", "the_theme_slug").'</h1>'; // My custom title
} else {
   the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); // the normal template title
}
```

This code is just a closer example, you will need to customize it a bit…

Comment: Thank you, what if I actually do not use a child theme, but have one main theme installed, would I just copy it in that theme´s folder? Saludos!

Comment: Wow, thats it. I was close in the meantime but you showed me a bit how php works. Thanks, it works. Thanks for taking your time! Really appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelSchwark Cool! Happy that this helped you.